# Forced logout crash with Qt & Opengl

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt4, ubuntu-10.04

I can't find any documentation on this issue so I figured it was time for a question:

We are writing an application that uses Qt and Opengl with some help from a homebrew singleton class. We have had good luck with it so far but I've just recently run into an amusing situation where if I run the program on my Ubuntu machine it will force a logout.

We do nothing to the machine in terms of user modification. I have a feeling it has something to do with the way we are initializing things, possibly with our timer.

I was curious if anyone had any small insight they might be able to give. Is this a known issue within Qt or Ubuntu?

*Note: I would give more information on the program but its very large and I only have a hint as to where to start.*

Comment: So... turns out that it does that when you don't call glInit() from your QGLWidget and then try to swapBuffers() on it. I had been calling initializeGL() without it. Silly me.

Comment: What? Ubuntu forced logout by "just" ommiting glInit() :D LoL

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a driver or X11 bug that causes a server crash. By definition a client must not be able to crash the X server. However it seems you're experiencing exactly that. There's probably nothing wrong on your side.

What to do: Report the problem to the developers of Xorg and Mesa. Provide a test case, ideally in source code form (try to reduce your programm to the most minimal version that still causes the crash).